# pip install to target directory fail

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-imaging-library

Hi I am planning to use AWS lambda where I need to package well my dependency libraries. The way they suggest is to use `pip install --target` to load all the dependencies into one place and bundle them later.

However, I am trying to use the PIL library to process jpgs where I am using pillow which is the actively maintained fork of PIL.

This is what I have done to make it work:

```
$ virtualenv env
$ source env/bin/activate
(env)$ pip install pillow 
...
   changing mode of /home/~/lambdaEnv/bin/pilconvert.py to 775
    changing mode of /home/~/lambdaEnv/bin/pilprint.py to 775
Successfully installed pillow-3.0.0
(env)$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Nov 21 2013, 10:50:32) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PIL import Image
>>>
```

And it worked perfect, however, when I use the `target` it errored out in a weird way. can anyone help me on this?

```
...
changing mode of /tmp/tmpbbKMTP/bin/pilconvert.py to 775
    changing mode of /tmp/tmpbbKMTP/bin/pilprint.py to 775
Successfully installed pillow-3.0.0
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/~/lambdaEnv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/~/lambdaEnv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 390, in run
    for item in os.listdir(lib_dir):
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmpbbKMTP/lib/python/'
```

And in the end there is nothing in the target directory.

Comment: getting same error in same situation with `MySQL-python`

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same problem, I didn't consider using `--target`, though it probably won't solve the problem. The reason is because PIL is using a C python libraries, such as `_imaging.so` which are linked again libraries located (by default) in your local library path, and are not present in the lambda environment. Here is how it looks like on my machine:

```
$ ldd PIL/_imaging.so 
...
    libjpeg.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8
...
```

So, when AWS will try to `import Imaging` in your python lambda, it will throw an error: `"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'handler'"` with the reason in the log:

```
START RequestId: GUID-GUID-GUID Version: $LATEST
Unable to import module 'handler': libjpeg.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Here is what you can do to overcome it (worked on my Ubuntu machine):
enforce pip (essentially, gcc) to link the shared libraries dependencies in the same (relative) directory of your lambda code:

```
# in your virtualenv directory:
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8 libjpeg.so.8
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 libfreetype.so.6 
ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 libpng12.so.0
source bin/activate
# Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to search libraries in the current folder
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH; pip install Pillow
```

Yon can now verify the dependencies' location by `ldd lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/*so`. Make sure you get, for example, `libjpeg.so.8 => ./libjpeg.so.8 (0x00007fa115985000)`.

You would then need to zip all the `so` files in your root directory, to the lambda package (of course, keep the same file tree).
That's it.

Note: If you want to keep your root directory cleaner, you can probably deploy the `so` files to `lib/` of your virtualenv. I didn't verify it.